# Python XML removing grandchildren and grandgrandchildren with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, xpath, elementtree

Let's use same XML as in ElemtTree documentation, just adding level of complexity. Added `<subdata>` at top level and added `<capital>` as child of `<country>`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <data>
    <subdata>
        <country name="Liechtenstein">
            <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
            <year>2008</year>
            <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
            <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E" />
            <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W" />
                <capital>
                <name>Vaduz</name>
                <anno>1860</anno>
                </capital>
        </country>
        <country name="Singapore">
            <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
            <year>2011</year>
            <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
            <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N" />
                <capital>
                <name>Singapore</name>
                <anno>1836</anno>
                </capital>
        </country>
        <country name="Panama">
            <rank updated="yes">69</rank>
            <year>2011</year>
            <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
            <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W" />
            <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E" />
                <capital>
                <name>Panama City</name>
                <anno>1530</anno>
                </capital>
        </country>
        </subdata>
    </data>
```

What I'm trying to do is to remove all `<capital>` elements with their subelements and data. And after removal has been done, I would like to save new XML file. I'm failing to successfuly remove `<capital>`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('country.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
capital = root.findall('.//capital')
for capital in root.findall('..//capital'):
    root.remove(capital)
tree.write('countryOutput.xml')
```

I have tried different methods of writing xpath to capital elements but so far no luck (skill).

My expected output should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <subdata>
        <country name="Liechtenstein">
            <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
            <year>2008</year>
            <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
            <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E" />
            <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W" />                   
        </country>
        <country name="Singapore">
            <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
            <year>2011</year>
            <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
            <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N" />                    
        </country>
        <country name="Panama">
            <rank updated="yes">69</rank>
            <year>2011</year>
            <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
            <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W" />
            <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E" />                   
        </country>
        </subdata>
    </data>
```

Comment: Is your goal to end up with an empty `subdata` element?

Comment: No, my goal is to remove `capital` element. Rest of data should stay the same.

Comment: I think you should edit the question and show us the exact wanted output.

Comment: So you actually want to remove `<capital>` elements, right? You did write "What I'm trying to do is to remove all `<country>` elements with their subelements and data", which confused me.

Comment: Yes, I actually want to remove `capital`. Sorry for mistake on post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a list of all the `<country>` elements. On each of these, remove the `<capital>` subelement.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
 
tree = ET.parse('country.xml')
countries = tree.findall('.//country')
 
for country in countries:
    capital = country.find("capital")
    country.remove(capital)
 
tree.write('countryOutput.xml')
```